# Sessions Don't Pesist across pages

Tags: javascript, php, css, session

trying to use sessions for usual authentication and updating but when i click a link, even to the same page it just flashes "incorect id" andi have to refresh and re login meaning users can't even update their own info let along navigate to other pages. Right now its on a subdomain not a full domain as i do the dev testing so maybe that's the issue but i figured id see if any keen eyes could spot an issue.

sessions are handled with an include at the top of every page that looks like this

```
<?php // accesscontrol.php
include_once 'common.php';
include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'messages.php';

session_start();

$uid = isset($_POST['uid']) ? $_POST['uid'] : $_SESSION['uid'];
$pwd = isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : $_SESSION['pwd'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if(!isset($uid)) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Please Log In for Access </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1> Login Required </h1>
<p>You must log in to access this area of the site. If you are
not a registered user, <a href="signup.php">click here</a>
to sign up for instant access!</p>
<p><form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
User ID: <input type="text" name="uid" size="8" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" SIZE="8" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form></p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
exit;
}
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
$_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd;

$link = dbConnect('db_name');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE
LOWER(username) = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strtolower($_POST[uid]))."' AND password = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strtolower($_POST[pwd]))."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (!$result) {
error('A database error occurred while checking your '.
'login details.\nIfhis error persists, please '.
'contact '.$adminemail.'.');
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['uid']);
unset($_SESSION['pwd']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Access Denied </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1> Access Denied </h1>
<p>Your user ID or password is incorrect, or you are not a
registered user on this site. To try logging in again, click
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">here</a>. To register for instant
access, click <a href="<?=$signuppage?>">here</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
exit;
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
$Middle_Name = $row['Middle_Name'];
$Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
$email = $row['email'];
$notes = $row['notes'];
$id = $row['ID'];
```

with the hosting paged formated similar to

```
<?php include 'includes/accesscontrol.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Members-Only Page </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/pwmeter.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/topnav.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?include('includes/nav_top_member.php');?>
<p>Welcome, <?=$username?>! You have entered a members-only area
of the site. Don't you feel special?</p>
```

Comment: if that to script is "accesscontrol.php" then your breaking your html on every page

Comment: You never set `$username` in `accesscontrol.php[`.

Comment: @nogad How is he breaking the HTML? All the blocks in `accesscontrol.php` that display HTML end with `exit`, so the error is shown instead of the HTML of the calling page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is using `$_POST['uid']` and `$_POST['pwd']`. If the user is already logged in, you need to use the session variable, not the POST parameter. That's in `$uid` and `$pwd`, which you set at the top of the script.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users 
        WHERE LOWER(username) = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strtolower($uid))."' 
        AND password = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strtolower($pwd))."'";
```

You should learn to use prepared queries and `mysqli_bind_param()` instead of escaping and concatenating. And you should not store plain-text passwords in the database, or ignore case when matching passwords.

Comment: yup that was it, can't believe i missed i had string to lower on password and was using post not the session, thanks. Figured it had to be a stupid oversight. As for Bind-Param i am looking into it its one reason i've got everything working off a included sub page i just just improve that one page instead of having to update a bunch of sub pages